# Let $M$ be a subset of a Hilbert space $H,$ and let $v,w \in H$. Suppose that $\langle v,x\rangle=\langle w,x\rangle$ for all $x \in M$ implies $v=w$.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let $M$ be a subset of a Hilbert space $H$, and let $v,w \in H$. Suppose that $ \langle v,x\rangle=\langle w,x\rangle$ for all $x \in M$ implies $v=w$. If this holds for all $v,w \in H$, show that $M$ is total in $H$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $v\perp M$ then, for all $x\in M$, we have $\langle v,x\rangle = 0 = \langle 0,x\rangle$, which by hypothesis implies $v=0$.